# Move picturebox on a specific point

Tags: c#, picturebox, points

I need to move a picturebox along array of specific points. The problem is when i manually locate the picturebox (before debugging), i can see it's locate in 100,100. But when i instruct it from source code :

```
Mfl1.Top = 100;
Mfl1.Left = 100;
```

after i run the program, they will be locate in different location.
What should i do to make it becomes a same 100,100? And where's the fault, is it in my screen resolution or what?

I've been frustated to look for the answer but seems like no one realize that picturebox have a different location before and after debugging. Thanks for your help!

*Someinfo, i've made the Forms resolution to be exact with my screen resolution.

Comment: So you want help moving a Client Side box from the Server Side?  Have you tried performing this action from the Client Side?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: _i can see it's locate in 100,100_  How are you determining the location to put it at?  Is it possible you're changing **containers** of said picturebox?